# How to fetch from one stream first and then pass to another stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I need to call cassandra to fetch a date and then pass the fetched date to another stream that is going to insert data into the database.

```
def fetchDate: Future[Done] =
  readJournal(persistenceKey)
    .drop(3)
    .take(1)
    .map(l => l.mydate)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)

def insertRowsToDb: Future[Done] = 
  readJournal(somePersistenceKey)
    .drop(4)
    .take(1)
    .map(data => MyClass(data))
    .mapAsync(1) { myData => 
      for {
        insert <- myRepository.insert(data.id, fetchDate) //error here because fetchDate is unavailable 
      }
    }

  class MyRepository(tableName: String) {
    def insert(id: String, fetchedDate: Long): Future[Int] =
      config.db.run {
        sqlu"""INSERT INTO #${tableName}
           VALUES (
            ${id},
            ${fetchedDate}
           )
          """
      }
```

**Question**

- How can I execute `fetchDate` first and then pass the result of it to `myRepository.insert` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is that `fetchDate` doesn't even hold the date! Fixing that means running with a `Sink` that does more than just "ignore":

```
def fetchDateFut: Future[Date] =
  readJournal(persistenceKey)
    .drop(3)
    .take(1)
    .map(l => l.mydate)
    .runWith(Sink.last)
```

Then, you need to `flatMap` your `Future` to bring into scope that date:

```
def insertRowsToDb: Future[Done] = fetchDateFut.flatMap { fetchDate: Date =>
  readJournal(somePersistenceKey)
    .drop(4)
    .take(1)
    .map(data => MyClass(data))
    .mapAsync(1) { myData => 
      for {
        insert <- myRepository.insert(data.id, fetchDate)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to grab the last element returned from `readJournal`? Instead of doing `drop(4)` and `take(1)`. I would like to grab the last event w/o pre-given knowledge of how many there are going to be

Comment: @Anthony I didn't realize that was your situation. In that case, just drop the `.drop(3)` and `.take(1)` altogether. `Sink.last` already just gets the last element in the stream.